# Flutter - Dependent dropdown menu using BloC

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am trying to create three dropdown menu School, Class and Group in a page and populating the menus from different APIs. Here School is a standalone dropdown, while Class dropdown depends on a value selected in School field and Group dropdown depends on a value selected in Class field for the respective menus to be populated.

School -> Class -> Group

How to implement this using bloc pattern. Any simple snippet on passing values between different widget through Bloc pattern would be really helpful.

Comment: Look at this provider package (https://pub.dev/packages/provider) it will help to to pass data between different widget